# keras - save epoch trace to file

Tags: keras, trace, epoch

I am running a neural net on keras. i would like to recoup all the epoch trace to analyze it after running the neural net. is there a simple way to save the info below to a txt file?

```
Epoch 16/75
183/183 [==============================] - 587s 3s/step - loss: 0.0079 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0585
- categorical_accuracy: 0.9836 - val_loss: 0.0797 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.2410 - val_categorical
_accuracy: 0.7901

Epoch 17/75
183/183 [==============================] - 587s 3s/step - loss: 0.0080 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0606
- categorical_accuracy: 0.9781 - val_loss: 0.0821 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.2395 - val_categorical
_accuracy: 0.8148
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for `CSVLogger` callback.

https://keras.io/callbacks/#csvlogger

```
csv_logger = CSVLogger('training.log')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[csv_logger])
```